# Which preposition to use: "For/In/Over/During the first week after I came here"?

Tags: grammaticality

If I want to say “I used to cook by myself for(in, over, during) the first week after I came here”, which preposition and sentence below should I use? Which are right and wrong among these sentences below?

a. In the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own.

b. During the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own.

c. For the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own.

d. Over the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own.

e. For/In/During/Over the first two weeks after I came here?

f. For/In/During/Over the first week of when I was here, I cooked on my own.

g. For/In/During/Over the first week since I came here, I cooked on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the words that I would use. In several cases, the answer is, "It depends on what the speaker is trying to say." In those cases, I have included more than one answer, with my "best guess" listed first and other possibilities afterwards.

> I used to cook by myself **for** the first week after I came here.
>
> c. **For** the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own.  *[most common phrasing]*
>
> a. **In** the first week after I came here, I cooked on my own. *[uncommon but possible]*
>
> e. **For/In/During/Over** the first two weeks after I came here, I cooked on my own.  *[I prefer "for" for most scenarios, but all are acceptable, with slightly varied shades of meaning.]*
>
> f. **For** the first week of when I was here, I cooked on my own.  *[The others don't make sense, because "the first week of when I was here" already implies a subset of the total time that you are talking about. Removing "of when" would make the other prepositions okay again.]*
>
> g. **NONE:** For/In/During/Over the first week since I came here, I cooked on my own.  *[Reason: You are describing a "first" week "since" you came here; the semantics don't work. I think what is intended is: "For the first week **after** I came here, I cooked on my own."]*

Note: Changing the prepositions in examples (e) and (g) would change the meaning:

- *For the first week after I came here*: Spans the entire first week.
- *In the first week after I came here*: Describes an event that occurred between the start and the end of that first week.
- *During the first week after I came here*: Like "in," but for an event that spanned time, e.g. "During the first week after I came here, I went to the bakery six times!"
- *Over the first week after I came here*: Somewhat less common. Related to "Over the course of the first week..."  Generally describes a progression, where you are comparing the situation at the start of the week versus the situation at the end of the week.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. I really appreciate it.